# Whirlpool Duet washer F3-E2 code not fixed by replacing temperature sensor

Tags: washer

My 12 year old `Whirlpool Duet` washer (model WFW9151YW00) started throwing an F3-E2 error mid cycle, refusing to finish. After googling that code, I replaced the temperature sensor located in the bottom of the drum in the back, cheap and easy. However, that did not fix it as the error happened again.

The other end of the wire from the sensor goes -- I think, because of the color -- in the drain in the front (see picture).

[image]

Are there any other things I should look at or is this totaled?

Comment: You haven't told us what the code message is.

Comment: it just says F3-E2, which I googled. the display is very basic