# Which part controls/limits basket oscillation in front load washers?

Tags: washer

I have narrowed [my problem](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/295705/whirlpool-duet-washer-f3-e2-code-not-fixed-by-replacing-temperature-sensor) down to the excessive oscillation of the basket drum, which then interferes with the temperature sensor that is attached to the rear casing. In normal operation, the basket should oscillate less (or be firmer) so that the amplitude does not interfere with the position of the sensor. I confirmed this by applying pressure to the basket and it was a lot more wobbly than the functioning front-load washer in my other investment property. Also, the washer can finish a small load cycle because there is less weight compounded with water but not a full load (more weight --> more wobbling --> sensor interference --> cycle disruption/error). But even when it finishes, the clothes are not drained of excess water, which I also think is consistent with excessive oscillation.

I did some [research](https://www.appliancepartspros.com/tub-basket-parts-for-whirlpool-wfw9151yw00.html) and found that it could be two parts that control/limit the wobbling of the basket drum: the [suspension spring](https://www.appliancepartspros.com/whirlpool-spring-280159-ap3904440.html) above it or the [shock absorber](https://www.appliancepartspros.com/whirlpool-shock-absr-w10822553-ap5985209.html) underneath. My question is, which of these two, or another third part is most likely responsible for this defect?

Answer (score 1):

In this application, only the shock absorber is limiting the oscillation. The springs are effectively allowing the drum to move around so that the shock absorber can absorb the vibrations.

As a double-check: springs in an application like this tend to only have two common failure modes, stretching, and snapping. Stretching requires being extended in a way that didn't happen here because the drum would have run into the tub. So if they aren't snapped, they are almost certainly fine.

Comment: that makes perfect sense, thank you. another question, because the documentation diagram i found is less than perfect: do you know if there is only one of these shock absorbers or 4? when I had the machine out and the back panel removed, I vaguely recollect 4 but can't remember because I wasn't paying close attention. I am asking because I need to order part(s)

Comment: nvrmnd, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPYpMHixNds) answered my question.